# How can I restart the PHP environment installed with Drush for Windows?

Tags: drush

I have installed Drush for Windows, works great, but it installs its own version of PHP in a subdir of the install directory.  I've increased the memory limit and execution times in that ini but how can I restart that PHP environment (if in fact that is even the correct PHP environment).  Short of restarting my machine (which is fine) just wondering what would be the way to do this?

Comment: I don't think you can. If you run phpinfo through your browser it will tell you which PHP you are running. It will most probably be the one that came with WAMP or whatever you installed, which is fine. Restarting IIS will restart that PHP version. To manage your PHP environment in Windows install PHP Manager for IIS.

Comment: This isn't a problem with WAMP or IIS (so the browser is irrelevant), those PHP versions are working perfectly fine and immediately have reflected changes to the php.ini when I made them and restarted the services.  The problem is the version Drush is using.

Comment: Not sure if you know this, but Aquia dev desktop works with one click install and Drush pre-installed.  I was using Xampp before and have to keep tweaking .ini files for timeouts ect...Aquai Dev desktop has none of these problems. Restarting the whole stack is as simple as shutting down Aquia and restarting. Additionally, I have chrome addon for timing page load, and it's faster.

Answer (score 1):

Drush works using CLI. It means it is not dependent on web server you are using. "Restarting environment" simply does not apply, Command Line Interface PHP is started each time you call drush, and stops when drush finishes it's job, that's all.

Comment: Interesting, well Drush for Windows installed its own PHP version in a subdirectory of the Drush install directory.  I've updated the php.ini there (and in my WAMP install) but it doesn't seem to be taking effect.  Any way to tell which PHP version it is using (PHP.exe directory)?

Comment: Add phpinfo.php file to a drupal install directory, open your console in there, and issue this command: drush scr phpinfo.php > phpdetails.txt, then inspect text file.